# How to conditionally reduce a changeset with Enum rather than If statements

Tags: elixir

I am encrypting a changeset with a bunch of optional fields, but I am currently using a ton of If statements to see if a changeset contains a field before trying to encrypt it.

I have a feeling there is an Enum function (like reduce) that would do this in a way that is idiomatically more Elixir, but none of what I have come up with is more performant than a ton of ugly If statements.

```
 def encrypt(changeset) do
    if changeset.changes["address"] do
      {:ok, encrypted_address} = EncryptedField.dump(changeset.changes.address, key_id)
      changeset
      |> put_change(:address, encrypted_address)
    end
    if changeset.changes["dob"] do
      {:ok, encrypted_dob} = EncryptedField.dump(changeset.changes.dob, key_id)
      changeset
      |> put_change(:address, encrypted_dob)
    end
    if changeset.changes["email"] do
      {:ok, encrypted_email} = EncryptedField.dump(changeset.changes.email, key_id)
      changeset
      |> put_change(:email, encrypted_email)
    end
   ...
 end
```

Comment: The code above won’t work as you expected in the first place. Remember all the data is immutable. Each `if` receives an original `changeset`.

Comment: thanks Aleksei! very quickly realized after trying to run the code above that it doesn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is to iterate through fields, conditionally updating the changeset:

```rb
def encrypt(changeset) do
  Enum.reduce(~w[address dob email]a, changeset, fn field, changeset ->
    if changeset.changes[field] do
      {:ok, encrypted} =
        EncryptedField.dump(changeset.changes[field], key_id)
      put_change(changeset, field, encrypted)
    else
      changeset # unlike your implementation this works
    end
  end)
end
```

---

Another way would be to [`Enum.filter/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#filter/2) the fields in the first place:

```rb
def encrypt(changeset) do
  ~w[address dob email]a
  |> Enum.filter(&changeset.changes[&1])
  |> Enum.reduce(changeset, fn field, changeset ->
    {:ok, encrypted} =
      EncryptedField.dump(changeset.changes[field], key_id)
    put_change(changeset, field, encrypted)
  end)
end
```

---

*Sidenote:* according to style guidelines by the core team, pipes are to be used if and only there are many links in the chain.

---

*Reply to the second answer:*

Idiomatic code using `with` would be:

```rb
def encrypt(changeset) do
  ~w[address dob email] |> Enum.reduce(changeset, fn field ->
    with %{^field => value} <- changeset.changes,
          {:ok, encrypted} <- EncryptedField.dump(value, key_id)
    do
      put_change(changeset, field, encrypted)
    else
      _ -> changeset
    end
  end)
end
```

Comment: This worked, but only after adding a second argument to the anonymous function, otherwise I got a /2 arguments in a func of arity /1 error -- e.g.: 
    ~w[address email]a, changeset,  fn field, changeset ->

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Aleksei's answer.

Another pattern in elixir is that if you have a series of checks before running an expression, you can use `with`.

Aleksei's code using `with` would be something like

```
def encrypt(changeset) do
  ~w[address dob email] |> Enum.reduce(changeset, fn field ->
    with \
      true <- Map.has_key?(changeset.changes, field),
      {:ok, encrypted} <- EncryptedField.dump(changeset.changes[field], key_id)
    do
      put_change(changeset, field, encrypted)
    else
      _ -> changeset
    end
  end)
end
```

Here, if `EncryptedField.dump` returns an `:error`, changeset is returned instead of throwing an exception if you do `{:ok, val} = EncryptedField.dump(...)`.

P.S: also recommend using `Map.has_key?`

Comment: If you want to go with `with`, I’d suggest pattern matching as more concise and explicit alternative to `Map.has_key?` instead of `true <- Map.has_key?(changeset.changes, field)` → `%{^field => value} <- changeset.changes, {:ok, encrypted} <- EncryptedField.dump(value, key_id)`. Filtering is still way better, though. FWIW, I have updated my answer with the complete example using `with`.

Comment: Right, thats nice!